# Using a JSON array in a POST request

Tags: json, r, http, post, httr

I'm writing an API [wrapper](https://github.com/erzk/PostcodesioR) to query UK postcodes using `httr` package and everything works fine when I use `GET` requests. I'm slightly lost when it comes to using a `POST` request.

Here's what the [documentation](http://postcodes.io/docs) of the API says:

> Accepts a JSON object containing an array of postcodes. Returns a list
>   of matching postcodes and respective available data.
>
> Accepts up to 100 postcodes.
>
> POST https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes?q=[postcode]
>
> Post Data
>
> This method requires a JSON object containing an array of postcodes to
>   be posted. E.g.
>
> {   "postcodes" : ["PR3 0SG", "M45 6GN", "EX165BL"] }

I tried the following:

```
library(httr)

pc_json <- '{
  "postcodes" : ["PR3 0SG", "M45 6GN", "EX165BL"]
}'

r <- POST(paste0("https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes?q=", pc_json, encode = "json"))
```

But it returns this:

> $status [1](https://github.com/erzk/PostcodesioR) 400
>
> $error [1](https://github.com/erzk/PostcodesioR) "Invalid JSON submitted. You need to submit a JSON object
>   with an array of postcodes or geolocation objects"

The same happens when I trim the array and use this:

```
r <- POST("https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes?q=EX165BL")
content(r)
```

I read similar threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26693842/how-do-i-post-a-json-formatted-request-to-get-json-data-from-a-url-in-r-into-the) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23705386/r-httr-post-of-json-returns-status-400), but they didn't make my problem any easier to solve.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: You and @marty_c might want to collaborate on a pkg. But why not write a pkg that syncs the [data](https://ons.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=e5f5ba4447fa419bb1244c64ed5202ae) and then does all the processing locally vs hit an API server? it'll be way faster & more efficient in the long run.

Comment: thanks for this contact. my plan in the long run was to query the data locally. the file holding the entire data seems pretty large so including this in the package is out of question. but it could be downloaded separately.

Comment: You can also put any JSON array into something that will pass through r with the `fromJSON()`  function from the httr package.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your almost there just need to format the postcodes as a list and use the body argument of `POST` then encode as `json`:

```
library(httr)

pc_json <- list(
  postcodes = c("PR3 0SG", "M45 6GN", "EX165BL")
)
res <- POST("https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes"
            , body = pc_json
            , encode = "json")
appData <- content(res)
```